# Durandal Widget not binding - no error

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, widget, durandal, single-page-application

I followed all the steps on the Durandal tutorial page but for whatever reason, the widget is not getting bound.

The following line is copied from browser, I am expecting it to be injected with the HTML from the widget.

```
 <div data-bind="widget: {kind:'dateMonthPicker', DateSubject: DateSubject}"></div>
```

Using the alternative syntax didn't get me any further either:

```
 <div data-bind="dateMonthPicker:{DateSubject: DateSubject}"></div>
```

I have placed the widget in what I believe to be the correct folder:

[image]

Also added the following lines to the start up routine:

```
app.configurePlugins({
    router: true, 
    dialog: true,
    widget: true,
    http: true
});


widget.registerKind('dateMonthPicker');
```

Any thoughts on what I could be missing? I don't think the code in the widget itself matters, because they are simply not getting called. I put a debugger in the `activate` line and it didn't even get there. The most frustrating part is probably the lack of error because I don't even know what I could be doing wrong.

Please help.

Comment: Could you post your `viewmodel.js` file?  I need to see what you're returning from it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out an exception was thrown in the parent ViewModel activation routine.

Exception was swallowed instead of propagated which made debugging it such a challenge.